# Remove User from Roles in ASP.NET Identity 2.0.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-roles, asp.net-identity-2

I customized some functionalities of Identity system to fit my needs.

I have the following ApplicationUserManager:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, long>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager()
        : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole,
            long, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>(new GestkatDbContext()))
    {
        //PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(10);
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser,long> store)
        : base(store)
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(
    IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
    IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, ApplicationUserLogin,
                ApplicationUserRole,ApplicationUserClaim>(
                context.Get<GestkatDbContext>()));

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator =
            new UserValidator<ApplicationUser,long>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                //RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };


        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
        };


        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        return manager;
    }

    public bool CreateUser(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        var idResult = this.Create(user, password);
        return idResult.Succeeded;
    }

    public bool AddUserToRole(long userId, string roleName)
    {
        return this.AddToRole(userId, roleName).Succeeded;
    }

    public bool ClearAllUserRoles(long userId)
    {
        foreach (var role in this.GetRoles(userId))
        {
            if (!this.RemoveFromRole(userId, role).Succeeded)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the other custom classes are:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one 
        // defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity =
            await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this,
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name, string description)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
    }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long> { }
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<long> { }

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<long> { }
```

Adding users and adding them to roles seems to be working fine. My problem is when I want to remove a user from roles.

When I want to Add user to a list of roles, I start clearing the user from all roles that he is already in with the method `ClearAllUserRoles(long userId)` and after I add him to each selected role. Like this:

```
public ActionResult UserRoles_Update(long RolesSelectedUserId, List<long> SelectedUserRoles)
    {
        if (RolesSelectedUserId == 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        userInfoRepository = new GenericRepository<UserInfo>(DB);
        UserInfo uInfo = userInfoRepository.GetByID(RolesSelectedUserId);
        UserManager.ClearAllUserRoles(uInfo.UserLoginInfo.Id);
        foreach (var roleId in SelectedUserRoles)
        {
            var roleName = DB.Roles.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == roleId).Name;
            if (!UserManager.AddUserToRole(uInfo.UserLoginInfo.Id, roleName))
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
        }
        return Json(true);
    }
```

My problem is that the `RemoveFromRole(userId, role)` method used in `ClearAllUserRoles(long userId)` only puts the fields `ApplicationUser_Id` and `ApplicationRole_Id` of my `AspNetUserRoles` table to null, leaving the fields `UserId` and `RoleId` filled so when I try to reassign the user to a role that he was already in the following exception is thrown:

```
{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUserRoles'. The duplicate key value is (16, 1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

My Questions are:

1. Should my `AspNetUserRoles` table have those 4 columns (`ApplicationUser_Id`, `ApplicationRole_Id`, `UserId`,`RoleId`) or I am doing something wrong in the `OnModelCreating()`method of my database context?
2. Is the `RemoveFromRole(userId, role)` method working as expected or it should delete the all row of `AspNetUserRoles` table?

**Update**

This is my `OnModelCreating()`method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        }

        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> table =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        table.Property((ApplicationUser u) => u.UserName).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<ApplicationUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().HasKey((ApplicationUserRole r) =>
            new { UserId = r.UserId, RoleId = r.RoleId }).ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUserLogin> entityTypeConfiguration =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().HasKey((ApplicationUserLogin l) =>
                new
                {
                    UserId = l.UserId,
                    LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider,
                    ProviderKey
                        = l.ProviderKey
                }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

        EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserClaim> table1 =
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

        EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationRole> entityTypeConfiguration1 =
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        entityTypeConfiguration1.Property((ApplicationRole r) => r.Name).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasRequired(p => p.UserInfo).WithOptional(p => p.UserLoginInfo);
    }
```

And in my Migration, the create table is like this:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    RoleId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    ApplicationUser_Id = c.Long(),
                    ApplicationRole_Id = c.Long(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.ApplicationRole_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationRole_Id);
```

Comment: The `ApplicationUserRole` table should only have `UserId` and `RoleId` columns.

Comment: @DavidG I think you are right, but I don't understand why extra columns are created. I've added the `OnModelCreating()` method can you take a look please?

Comment: Do you really need all that code in `OnModelCreating`? Isn't it pretty much all done for you if your context is inheriting from `IdentityDbContext`?

Comment: @DavidG As I have some need to costumize the Identity system to fit my needs (addins more info for the user, primary keys as `long` instead of `string`, etc.) it was the way I found to make it working. Do you think that it could be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the default naming of the foreign keys in your `OnModelBuilding`

replace

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<ApplicationUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
```

with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(p => p.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany(p => p.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.RoleId);
```

I would suggest, however, that you make a call to `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` at the start of the method, and let the stock IdentityDbContext do most of this for you.